# Couchbase spring configuration connection issue

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I was trying to configure couchdb with spring but when i deploy the project it gives me java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

and the dataSource.xml defined below configs. values are read from property file.

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:properties/dataSource.properties" />

<!-- establish couch db connection -->
<couchbase:couchbase bucket="${couch.dbName}" password="" host="${couch.host}" />

<couchbase:template/>
<couchbase:repositories base-package="com.link.twitter.repository"/>
```

These are the dependencies I used in my POM

```
<!-- Spring data couchbase -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.data.couchbase.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId> 
    <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId> 
    <version>${couchbase.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the exception Im getting when its deploying.

```
DEBUG CouchbaseConfigConnection:84 - Reconnecting due to failure to `connect to {QA sa=/127.0.0.1:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null,` topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:677)
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:436)
at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection.run(CouchbaseConnection.java:325)
```

how can i fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB listen for requests on port `5984` by default - your request was sent to `127.0.0.1:11210` and gots rejected.

Change the value of the config param `bind_address` to `11210`

Comment: Changing the bind address won't work. The client that @Neero is asking about does not work with CouchDB.

Comment: I was working with cent os 7. It doesnt work for me then I downgrade the my OS to cent os 6 and try it. Then its worked. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase and CouchDB are two different products. Your trying to use the Couchbase java client against Couchbase and that will not work. See the http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb for more information on the difference between the two products.

Comment: Yep I know I was trying to make connection with the couchbase. And this is the implementation for the couchbase.I changed my title and sorry about that. Thanks for the response.